# OnChange Change the Variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing project on online shopping on PHP now I am stuck on changing the value
I want to convert the currency to other currency rate

```
<select onchange="">
    <option value="60">US</option>
    <option value="88">Euro</option>
    <option value="72">Pond</option>
</select>
```

So when user change the option it automatically multiply with all variables on the page like if I am using `$price` to echo the price in Euro, when user change it to US is will multiply `$price` with US value which is 60 and so on for other.

```
$price = 150

    Price in Euro: <?php echo $price*88; ?>
```

so when user change the value it changes like this

```
$price = 150

Price in Dollar: <?php echo $price*60; ?>
```

Comment: You need JavaScript to do this

Comment: @JohnConde like how? I don't know much about javaScript

Comment: Look into event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is: [the link to the Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fEYjK/)

Your Html Code:

```
   <select id ="currency" onchange="convert()">
      <option value="60">US</option>
      <option value="88">Euro</option>
      <option value="72">Pound</option>
    </select>        

    <div class="text_input">
        New Price <input id="txtValue" type="text" />            
    </div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
 function convert() {    
 var price = 150;
 var selectedPrice = document.getElementById('currency');
 var currency = selectedPrice.options[selectedPrice.selectedIndex].text;
 var currencyValue = document.getElementById('currency').value; 

  switch(currency)
  {
    case 'US':
        newPrice = price * currencyValue;
        break;
    case 'Euro':
        newPrice = price * currencyValue;
        break;
    case 'Pound':
        newPrice = price * currencyValue;
        break;        
   }
 //Display the new price to the user
 document.getElementById("txtValue").value = newPrice;
           }
```

If you want to use jQuery, you can remove the onchange from the select input control in your html code then do the following in your jquery code:

```
 $("#currency").change(function() { 
 var price = 150;
 var selectedPrice = document.getElementById('currency');
 var currency = selectedPrice.options[selectedPrice.selectedIndex].text;
 var currencyValue = document.getElementById('currency').value; 

  switch(currency)
  {
    case 'US':
        newPrice = price * currencyValue;
        break;
    case 'Euro':
        newPrice = price * currencyValue;
        break;
    case 'Pound':
        newPrice = price * currencyValue;
        break;        
   }
 //Display the new price to the user
 document.getElementById("txtValue").value = newPrice;

 });
```

Comment: The switch case is redundant as it does the same thing in all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much shorter implementation.

In your HTMl, store the 'original price' and the 'calculated price':

```
<input type="hidden" id="original_price" value="150" />
Price: <input type="text" id="calculated_price" value="9000" />
<select onchange="updatePrice(this.value)">
    <option value="60">US</option>
    <option value="88">Euro</option>
    <option value="72">Pond</option>
</select>
```

And your JavaScript would look like this:

```
function updatePrice(val) {
    p = document.getElementById("original_price").value;
    newp = p * val;
    document.getElementById("calculated_price").value = newp;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e89cz/2/